# Getting issue @State binding form Model to View - Swift UI

Tags: swiftui

I am using a model struct:

```
    struct JobTemplate : Identifiable {
        @State var textFieldValue: String = ""
    }
```

I want to bind 'textFiledValue' to TextFiled in View, but it is not working.

```
    struct NewJobsView: View {
            var jobTemplate = JobTemplate()
            var body: some View {
                VStack {
                        TextField(title, text: jobTemplate.$textFieldValue)
                       }
              } 
    }
```

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 3):

Here is possible solution

```
struct JobTemplate : Identifiable {
    var id = UUID()
    var textFieldValue: String = ""
}

struct NewJobsView: View {
    @State var jobTemplate = JobTemplate()
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TextField("", text: $jobTemplate.textFieldValue)
        }
    }
}
```

alternate is to use `ObservableObject` view model holding `JobTemplate` as `@Published` property and use it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use @State in your main view and refer to the `jobTemplate` struct there.

```
struct JobTemplate : Identifiable {
    var id = // Unique identifier, possibly a UUID
    var textFieldValue: String = ""
}

struct NewJobsView: View {
    @State var jobTemplate = JobTemplate()

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TextField(title, text: $jobTemplate.textFieldValue)
        }
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should only use a `@State var` from the view's body. Subsequently, you can bind said `@State var` to your view's child view(s).

Here's the documentation:

> You should only access a state property from inside the view’s body, or from methods called by it. For this reason, declare your state properties as private, to prevent clients of your view from accessing it.
>   https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/state

If you're looking for an object to store various states to update a view, I suggest using an `ObservedObject` instead. Put `NewJobsView()` in the body of your `ContentView`:

```swift
class JobTemplateViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var textFieldValue: String = ""
}

struct NewJobsView: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel = JobTemplateViewModel()
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TextField("Title", text: $viewModel.textFieldValue)
            Text(viewModel.textFieldValue)
        }
    }
}
```